# Do I need an ID! for all types in the schema in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Do all types need a non-null ID? I am creating a schema and can't think of a type that wouldn't need an ID and yet most tutorials I see do not include ID.

Comment: If you had a general `Point` type with an `x` and `y` for example, that wouldn't make sense to have an ID.

Comment: Thanks this was what I was wondering